# How can I modify swagger-ui.html for springfox?

Tags: springfox

I am using springfox's swagger implementation. I would like to modify the swagger-ui.html to take a custom header value. How do I modify this file? Or tell spring fox to use an alternate file?

Comment: I was able to acheive this by following the instructions here: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1176 Basically, You can pull down the source and make whatever modifications you need to make. You don't need to create a web jar. just copy it into your resources and have your app handle it using resource handlers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to customize swagger-ui quite a bit, I would just recommend adding a private copy of swagger-ui to your web application resources and modify the ui based on your needs.

Swagger-ui bundled with springfox is *optional*.

Comment: how to understand 'quite a bit' ? what about changing the logo, require password to login to view and see different content based on different login?

Comment: That is quite a bit :)

Comment: @actan. Were you able to change the swagger logo? I'm  desperately looking for some clue to change the swagger logo in spring boot.

Comment: @Avinash yes I copied the swagger static resource into project and customized whatever I need, logo was updated

Comment: Not good if you need to have Authorize Button in Swagger

Answer (score 4):

1. Pull Swagger UI from github.

   https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui
2. Copy & paste *dist* directory of swagger ui to *resources* directory
3. Replace the code with below in swagger config

   replace

   ```
   registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
   ```

   with

   ```
   registry.addResourceHandler("**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/dist/");
   ```
4. Change the api docs path in index.html to your path

   Replace

   ```
   http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json
   ```

   With

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/your_app/v2/api-docs
   ```
5. Use the below url pattern to see the ui page

   http://localhost:8080/your_app/index.html

Comment: thanks, that works, but deep linking doesnt work (I get error when sending link to specific opened endpoint in swagger). Any idea how to fix it? thanks!

Comment: UPDATE as of now: In step no. 3, the Line "registry.addResourceHandler("**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/dist/");" does not work, as now SpringBoot has default mappings of /static, /resources. /META-INF/resources. Thus, the /dist mapping does not work. Also, the "**" flag is also invalid, you have to provide valid html page name. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pull the swagger ui into your project and follow the steps here:
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1176

Then edit the index.html and change where it points to the petstore to your endpoint. ( i.e. "http://localhost:8080/MyProjectName/v2/api-docs");

```
 $(function () {
  var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
  if (url && url.length > 1) {
    url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
  } else {
    url = "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json";
```